# Find 2nd Key in BST

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I posted something yesterday and got some help to get started, and I feel like I am almost there now.  I have created a BST, with the primary key as a name, and the secondary key as that persons weight. I have managed to finish everything I need except for searching for the lowest weight (secondary key).  My method to search the minimum weight is a preorder traversal, and it outputs all of the weights correctly to the screen.  What is the technique to go about for determining which is the lowest now?  I've tried a few different if statements, and creating a minwt int, but am having no luck getting to work (I think it has something to do with the recursion).  Anyways, here is the code.  Any help, like always, is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class tNode
{
public:
    string name;
    int wt;
    tNode *left, *right;

    tNode()
    {
        left = right = 0;
    }

    tNode(string name, int wt, tNode *l = 0, tNode *r = 0)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->wt = wt;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
};

class bSTree
{
public:
    tNode *root;

    bSTree()
    {
        root = 0;
    }

    bool add(string name, int wt)
    {
        tNode *temp = root, *prev = 0;
        while (temp != 0)
        {
            prev = temp;
            if (name < temp->name)
            {
                temp = temp->left;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = temp->right;
            }
        }

        if (root == 0)
        {
            root = new tNode(name, wt);
        }
        else if (name < prev->name)
        {
            prev->left = new tNode(name, wt);
        }
        else if (name > prev->name)
        {
            prev->right = new tNode(name, wt);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void searchWeight(tNode* temp)
    {
        // DETERMINE LOWEST WEIGHT CONTAINED IN TREE

        if (temp != 0)
        {
            cout << temp->wt << endl;
            searchWeight(temp->left);
            searchWeight(temp->right);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: If you're traversal works correctly, then you're 99% there.  You need a variable to hold the lowest weight, and the lowest key -- only set them when an object in the tree meets the appropriate criteria, then output them when you're traversal is complete.

Comment: Thanks Chad, that is what I have been trying but it is not working properly.  I will keep messing around with it though, now I know that I'm on the right track.

Comment: I've provided an answer with a hint on how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some temporary variables to hold the lowest weight and associated key.  They need to be accessible outside of the scope of your `searchWeight()` function.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int lowest_weight = 999999;  // Something sufficiently high
string lowest_weight_key;

class tNode
{
    /*...*/
    void searchWeight(tNode* temp)
    {
        // DETERMINE LOWEST WEIGHT CONTAINED IN TREE

        if (temp != 0)
        {
            // if temp->wt is lower than lowest weight
            // set lowest_weight equal to temp->wt
            // and set lowest_weight_key equal to temp->name

            cout << temp->wt << endl;
            searchWeight(temp->left);
            searchWeight(temp->right);
        }
    }
};
```

Now, just print out the values of `lowest_weight` and `lowest_weight_key` after calling `searchWeight()`.

Comment: Fantastic, got it working.  Thanks!  I was doing something similar, but just wasn't putting the variables outside of the method.